# What are the odds of winning the lottery in Like a Dragon: Ishin?

Tags: like-a-dragon-ishin

There is [a lottery booth in the Fushimi district](https://guides.gamepressure.com/like-a-dragon-ishin/guide.asp?ID=67795) where you can spend tickets to attempt to win a prize. There are 5 different prizes: Special prize, first prize, second prize, third prize, and fourth prize.

What are the odds of winning each prize at the lottery booth?

[image: Lottery booth prizes]
<sub>[Screenshot from gamepressure.com](https://guides.gamepressure.com/like-a-dragon-ishin/guide.asp?ID=67795)</sub>